# I withdrew my BTC coins to a NEO wallet Did i lose my coins? How can i recover them?

Tags: alternatives, cross-chain-recovery, bittrex

After a long corrospondance with Bittrex support staff i was given the following information.

"If you have sent BTC to a NEO address, these wallets have addresses that validate to each other, but the wallets are not compatible for receiving coins. You'll need to research how to remove a private key from a NEO address and import it into a BTC wallet to recover these coins. You may want to contact someone from the NEO community for help.  We can be of no further assistance on this issue."

How can i reverse this?

Answer (score 1):

The response it pretty clear , you need to find a way to extract the private key of the neo wallet and import it into some other BTC wallet which allows you to do that.

What wallet are you using for NEO?

I cannot comment if this will work though as i have no idea how the Private,Public keys are generated for NEO.